# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError) on callback passed to react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm stuck with a problem passing callback function to a component.
This is a small piece of my App.js file

```
loginCompleted = (status) => {
        if (status == "1") {
            this.setState({ currentUser: "xxxx" });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <MainTemplate authStatus={ this.state.currentUser }>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} loginCompleted={this.loginCompleted}  />
                    </Switch>
                </MainTemplate>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```

As you can see I want to pass the loginCompleted callback to the Login component.

In the Login component there is this function that handle the submit form

handleSubmit = async e => {
e.preventDefault();
const token = await this.LoginService.loginUser(this.state.username, this.state.password);
if (token) {
console.log(token);
this.props.loginCompleted(token);
this.props.history.push("/home");
}
else {
console.log("NULL");
}
}

I recevice the error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.loginCompleted is not a function
```

Despite the research I still don't understand why. Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that you are passing prop to the route, not to the component itself. Try this approach.

> ```
> loginCompleted = (status) => {
>         if (status == "1") {
>             this.setState({ currentUser: "xxxx" });
>         }
>     }
>
>     render() {
>         return (
>             <BrowserRouter>
>                 <MainTemplate authStatus={ this.state.currentUser }>
>                     <Switch>
>                         <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
>                         <Route exact path='/login'> 
>                           <Login loginCompleted={this.loginCompleted}  />
>                        </Route>
>                     </Switch>
>                 </MainTemplate>
>             </BrowserRouter>
>         );
>     }
> ```

We wrap the Component inside of Route and pass the prop to component, not to route.

Comment: Noooooooo! What a stupid mistake:-( Thank you very much!

Comment: It happens when you are too tired))  You are welcome!

Comment: Thank you for your understanding!